# arara: XeLaTeX engine FAILURE after changing file to reference

Tags: xetex, arara

I changed file to reference in my `xelatx.yaml`:

```yaml
!config
identifier: xelatex
name: XeLaTeX
authors:
- Paulo
commands:
- name: XeLaTeX engine
  command: >
    @{
        if (isEmpty(directory)) {
            return getCommand('xelatex', interaction, shell,
                   synctex, options, reference);
        }
        else {
            return getCommandWithWorkingDirectory(directory, 'xelatex',
                   interaction, shell, synctex, options, reference);
        }
    }
arguments:
- identifier: interaction
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'batchmode', 'nonstopmode', 'scrollmode',
              'errorstopmode' ].contains(parameters.interaction)) {
            return '--interaction='.concat(parameters.interaction);
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided interaction value is not valid.');
        }
    }
- identifier: shell
  flag: >
    @{
        isTrue(parameters.shell, '--shell-escape', '--no-shell-escape')
    }
- identifier: synctex
  flag: >
    @{
        isTrue(parameters.synctex, '--synctex=1', '--synctex=0')
    }
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
- identifier: directory
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.directory;
    }
```

Header in my TeX file:

```latex
% arara: xelatex: { 
% arara: --> shell: yes, 
% arara: --> synctex: yes, 
% arara: --> directory: subdir, 
% arara: --> files: [ dok-ext-01.tex,dok-ext-01.tex,dok-ext-01.tex, 
% arara: --> dok-ext-02.tex, dok-ext-02.tex,dok-ext-02.tex, 
% arara: --> dok-ext-03.tex, dok-ext-03.tex, dok-ext-03.tex 
% arara: --> ] 
% arara: --> } 
% arara: xelatex: { 
% arara: --> shell: yes, 
% arara: --> synctex: yes, 
% arara: --> files: [maintex, main.tex, main.tex] }
```

I got

> XeLaTeX engine FAILURE

I can't resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, path woes. `:)`

You were very close to a solution! Replace `reference` by `reference.getName()` and it should work again:

```
!config
identifier: xelatex
name: XeLaTeX
authors:
- Paulo
commands:
- name: XeLaTeX engine
  command: >
    @{
        if (isEmpty(directory)) {
            return getCommand('xelatex', interaction, shell,
                   synctex, options, reference.getName());
        }
        else {
            return getCommandWithWorkingDirectory(directory, 'xelatex',
                   interaction, shell, synctex, options, reference.getName());
        }
    }
arguments:
- identifier: interaction
  flag: >
    @{
        if ([ 'batchmode', 'nonstopmode', 'scrollmode',
              'errorstopmode' ].contains(parameters.interaction)) {
            return '--interaction='.concat(parameters.interaction);
        }
        else {
            throwError('The provided interaction value is not valid.');
        }
    }
- identifier: shell
  flag: >
    @{
        isTrue(parameters.shell, '--shell-escape', '--no-shell-escape')
    }
- identifier: synctex
  flag: >
    @{
        isTrue(parameters.synctex, '--synctex=1', '--synctex=0')
    }
- identifier: options
  flag: >
    @{
        if (isList(parameters.options)) {
            return parameters.options;
        }
        else {
            throwError('I was expecting a list of options.');
        }
    }
- identifier: directory
  flag: >
    @{
        return parameters.directory;
    }
```

Hope it helps!